# Show properties of differentiable function $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differentiable function in $(a,+\infty), a>0$

- $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)=L \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty\} \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to +\infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=L$.
- Using e.g. the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin{(x^2)}}{x}$, show that the converse of the above does not hold.
- Does the converse hold if we know that there exist in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty\}$ the limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)$ ?

For the first question, I have tried the following:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)=L \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \to +\infty} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \lim_{x \to +\infty} (f(x+h)-f(x))=L$$

Does this help somehow?

As for the second question, we have that

$0 \leq \left| \frac{\sin{(x+1)^2}}{x+1}\right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{x+1}\right|$.

Since $\frac{1}{x+1} \to 0$ while $x \to + \infty$, it follows that $\frac{\sin{(x+1)^2}}{x+1} \to 0$, while $x \to +\infty$. Similarly, we get that $\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x} \to 0$, while $x \to +\infty$.

Thus

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left( \frac{\sin{(x+1)^2}}{x+1}-\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x}\right)=0.$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left( \frac{\sin{(x^2)}}{x}\right)'=2 \cos{(x^2)}-\frac{\sin{(x^2)}}{x^2}$$

But $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \cos{x^2}$ does not exist. So the converse does not hold.

As for the third question, we have that

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=L$$

$$f'(x+1)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+1+h)-f(x+1)}{h}$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0 } \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1+h)-f(x+1)}{h}$$

We also have that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (f(x+h+1)-f(x+h))=L$.

Thus we get that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Does this help somehow?

Comment: Hint for the first one : $f(x+1)-f(x) = \int_{x}^{x+1} f'(x) dx$, you would need to be careful about the cases where $L\in \{ \pm \infty \}$.

Comment: @P.Quinton If $L \in \mathbb{R}$, then $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \int_{x}^{x+1} f'(x)dx$$

We have that $|f'(x)| \leq \max |f'(x)| \leq L$.

$$\int_{x}^{x+1} f'(x) dx \leq \int_{x}^{x+1} |f'(x)| dx \leq \int_{x}^{x+1} L dx=L$$

Since $\int_{x}^{x+1} f'(x) dx \leq L$, we have that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) dx=L$.

Is everything right?


How to we proceed when $L \in \{ \pm \infty \}$ ?

Comment: I don't think that $\max |f'(x)|\leq L$, however what you can say is $\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)\leq \int_x^{x+1} f'(x)dx \leq \max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)$, both the left and right bounds converges to $L$.

Comment: Do we have: $$\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)\leq \int_x^{x+1} f'(x)dx \leq \max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u) \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\int_x^{x+1} f'(x)dx \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)$$ As $x\rightarrow +\infty$ then $u\rightarrow +\infty$, so do we get at the left and right side of the inequality the limit as for $u$ ? @P.Quinton

Comment: So we get $$\lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\int_x^{x+1} f'(x)dx \leq \lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}\max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)\\  \Rightarrow \lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))\leq \lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}\max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)$$ Does this mean that $\lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)= \lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}\max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)=L$ since $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)=L$ ?  @P.Quinton

Comment: The limit is for $x$ going to $\infty$. and yes if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = L$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)=L$. You can see that from the definition of such a limit : $\forall \epsilon\exists x_0$ such that $\forall x>x_0,|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon$, you can prove that it works for $\min$ by taking the new $x_0'=x_0+1$

Comment: Why do we take at the definition $x_0'=x_0+1$ ? I got stuck right now. @P.Quinton

Comment: Actually you don't need it : since for all $x>x_0$, we have $|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon$, then for all $x>x_0$ you have $|\min_{u\in[x,x+1)} f'(x) - L|<\epsilon$ which proves that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \min_{u\in[x,x+1)} f'(x)=L$

Comment: Ahh ok! The same holds also for $\max$ instead of $\min$, right? @P.Quinton

Comment: Yes. It follows from the same argument.

Comment: Ok! So it follows that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\left (f(x+1)-f(x)\right )=L$$ Does all this hold only in the case $L\in \mathbb{R}$ ? When $L=\pm \infty$ do we have the following? @P.Quinton

Comment: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\int_x^{x+1} f'(x)dx \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)$$ 
If $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)=L$ where $L=+\infty$ then $\forall M>0 \ \exists x_0: \forall x>x_0 : f'(x)>M$. It also holds that $$\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)>M \ \text{ and } \ \max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)>M$$ and so the result is then again as the previous one. 
@P.Quinton

Comment: If $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)=L$ where $L=-\infty$ then $\forall M<0 \ \exists x_0: \forall x>x_0 : f'(x)<M$. It also holds that $$\min_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)>M \ \text{ and } \ \max_{u\in [x,x+1)}f'(u)>M$$ and so the result is then again as the previous one. 
$$$$ 
Is this correct? @P.Quinton

Comment: Yes it is correct, except the last one the inequalities are in the wrong direction

Comment: Oh yes, you are right!! So the first part is done! Is the second part correct as I did it in my original post above? @P.Quinton